# Autoscaling ec2 instance without loss of old data

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

Recently My Website  shifted on Amazon.

1. I create EC2 Instance. Install lamp and Setup CodeIgnitor in /var/www/http folder.
   the structure
2. Codeignitor folder I have folder name 'UPLOAD'.this folder is used for uploaded images and files.
3. I make AMI image from EC2 Instance.
4. I have setup Auto scaling of Ec2 instances.
5. When my old ec2 instance is failed then automatically new instance is created. But My all data from "UPLOAD" of folder on old ec2 instance has lost.
6. I want to separate "UPLOAD" folder in codeignitor from ec2 instance. 
   So whenever new instance is create it will get UPLOAD folder and its contents without loss.

I want to separate this upload folder. so when new instance is create then it will get this data.
how to do this.
Thanks for Advance.

Note . I have used MYSQL on Amazon RDS.

Comment: You want to read about share nothing architecture. Your user data needs to move to s3 or other storage mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared [Elastic Block Storage](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) mounted directory.

If you manually configure your stack using the AWS Console, go to the EC2 Service in the console, then go to Elastic Block Storage -> Volumes -> Create Volume. And in your launch configuration you can bind to this storage device.

If you are using the command line tool as-create-launch-config to create your launch config, you need the argument

> --block-device-mapping "key1=value1,key2=value2..."

If you are using [Cloudformation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) to provision your stack, refer to [this template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/Gollum_Single_Instance_With_EBS_Volume.template) for guidance.

This assumes Codeignitor can be configured to state where its UPLOAD directory is.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, as EBS volumes cannot be shared between instances. I have posted a similar question here:  https://serverfault.com/q/978511/50948

Answer (score 1):

As said by Mike, you can use **EBS**, but you can also use [Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to store your images.

This way, whenever an instance starts, it can access all the previously uploaded images from S3. Of course, this means that you must change your code for the upload, to use the AWS API and not the filesystem to store your images to S3.

Comment: @talai : Thanks Talai . what is fast to access by PHP(codeignitor) S3 or EBS? and is there any link to guide how to store images on S3 via Codeignitor.

Comment: I don't know about Codeignitor, but there is a [PHP SDK for Amazon AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) that you can use. And in my opinion, EBS is faster than S3. The difference is that you can make the files stored on S3 accessible to anybody and from anywhere (if you want to, you can configure the security settings), but for EBS, you must pass through an EC2 instance.